# Protótipos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Para que serve os seguintes métodos:

- hasOwnProperty();
- getPrototypeOf();

E qual sua função no código abaixo:

```
var carro = {};
carro.modelo = 'Celta';
carro.marca = 'Chevrolet';
carro.hasOwnProperty('modelo');
Object.getPrototypeOf(carro);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conhecer mais sobre leia [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

```js
var carro = {};
carro.modelo = 'Celta';
carro.marca = 'Chevrolet';
console.log(carro.hasOwnProperty('modelo')); // retorna um boolean indicando se o objeto possui a propriedade especificada.
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf('carro')); // retorna o prototype (isto é, o valor da propriedade interna [[Prototype]]) do objeto especificado.
```